# In Angular, how to change handle of the primeng's slider handle?

Tags: angular, slider, primeng

`Prime ng` is used inside our project and I tried everything, but I couldn't change the width of the slider handle. I could however change the background color. How can I change the primeng slider handle's style? The class seems to be `.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle`  but I tried to change the width through it, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to change the style by wrapping the existing element into another div with an id set for it. Then, being specific and targeting only the element with THAT class being a child of THAT (newly created) element. However, the origin class I couldn't change in no way, and I'd love to be able to do it. If anyone knows how, please feel free to make another answer that is better.